# Tap/Touch function on adding/removing images on corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I am trying to make a game, similar to Simon Says. I am currently using the corona sdk, and I would be very grateful if you were to help me with this! 
I have already defined my box1 variable with an image. I am trying to make it so when I click the image of the box, another box of different color shows up on top of it. I would like it so the box that appears disappears when I let go of my mouse. Below is part of my code:

```
local function lightbox(event)
if event.phase == "began" then
    local clickedbox1 = display.newImage("clickedbox.png")
    clickedbox1.x = display.contentWidth/5
    clickedbox1.y = display.contentWidth/2
end
if event.phase == "ended" then
    clickedbox1: removeself()
    clickedbox1 = nil
end
end

-->Add the listener to our boxes
box1:addEventListener("touch", lightbox)
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **event.target.x** inside of your **touch function** so that the popupbox will be displayed on top of the touched image.

**NOTE:** Change the image assets given to your image assets

```
local popupImage

local onTouchListener = function(event)

    if (event.phase == "began" ) then

        popupImage = display.newImageRect("images/btn_cancel_reset.png", 55,18)
        popupImage.x = event.target.x
        popupImage.y = event.target.y


    elseif(event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "moved") then
        --ADD EVENT.PHASE == "MOVED" SINCE THE IMAGE WILL NOT BE REMOVED 
        --WHEN YOU TOUCH AND DRAG YOUR MOUSE. YOU CAN REMOVE IT IF YOU WANT

        if (popupImage ~= nil) then

            popupImage:removeSelf()
            popupImage = nil

        end
    end


end


local btnclick = display.newImageRect("images/btn_buy_more_error.png", 126,18)
btnclick.x = display.contentWidth/2
btnclick.y = display.contentHeight/2
btnclick:addEventListener( "touch", onTouchListener)
```

Comment: No prob mate! Happy Coding and Goodluck!